# JavaScript: List of dictionaries(JSON) to csv

Tags: javascript

I am doing some operation on list of dictionaries and at the end want to save the data in the form of csv in browser's local storage.

My list of dictionaries data looks like this:

```
[{
    arrivalAddress: "Address"
arrivalLat: "72.989506"
arrivalLon: "19.149307"
arrivalTimeEnd: "8/8/2020 13:37"
arrivalTimeStart: "8/8/2020 13:37"
carrier: "ABC"
departureAddress: "abc,sdkfnv"
departureLat: "73.008304"
departureLon: "19.114599"
departureTime: "8/8/2020 13:37"
hazardousGoods: "TRUE"
id: "1"
"receiver ": "Tom"
sender: "Jack"
tourID: "abc"
vehicleClass: "eu_heavy"
},
arrivalAddress: "Address"
arrivalLat: "72.989506"
arrivalLon: "19.149307"
arrivalTimeEnd: "8/8/2020 13:37"
arrivalTimeStart: "8/8/2020 13:37"
carrier: "ABC"
departureAddress: "abc,sdkfnv"
departureLat: "73.008304"
departureLon: "19.114599"
departureTime: "8/8/2020 13:37"
hazardousGoods: "TRUE"
id: "1"
"receiver ": "Tom"
sender: "Jack"
tourID: "abc"
vehicleClass: "eu_heavy"
},
......

]
```

And I want it to save in browser's local storage like this:

[image]

*Can anyone help me to convert list of dicts to csv?*

Comment: All data in `locaStorage` is saved as a `string` format. How are you saving the data please add your code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
const listOfDicts = [...];

const dictionaryKeys = Object.keys(listOfDicts[0]);

const dictValuesAsCsv = listOfDicts.map(dict => (
  dictionaryKeys.map(key => dict[key]).join(',')
));

const result = [dictionaryKeys.join(','), ...dictValuesAsCsv].join('\n');
```

Mind you, the order of the keys might not be correct, for that you should first sort `dictionaryKeys` to be in the correct order (if the keys are constant, you can replace `const dictionaryKeys = Object.keys(listOfDicts[0]);` with `const dictionaryKeys = ['key1', 'key2', ...];`)

---

**Edit:**

To answer your question about commas in the values, here's the change you should make

```
const dictValuesAsCsv = listOfDicts.map(dict => (
  dictionaryKeys.map(key => {
    if (dict[key].includes(',')) {
      return `"${dict[key]}"`;
    }
   
    return dict[key];
  }).join(',')
));
```

Explanation: the only difference is that you don't simply return `dict[key]`, but rather you first check if it contains a comma; if it does, you wrap it in quotes, else it stays as before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, column names are perfect but all rows are in single row, any idea how to break the row in new line?

Comment: Oh yes, I think I made a small mistake.

I think the last line should be
`const result = [dictionaryKeys.join(','), ...dictValuesAsCsv].join('\n');`
(notice the `...` spread operator before `dictValuesAsCsv`).

Can you please try it and let me know if it works? If it does, I'll make sure to edit the original answer with the correction.

Comment: I know this is not part of my question but while converting to csv I am getting some problem boz in one cell I have value as `abc,sdkfnv` and in final result I am getting as `abc` and `sdkfnv` in two different cells, any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, you can escape commas using quotes. I've edited my post with an answer to this question.

Comment: is there an npm lib that handles the writing and reading of these lists of dicts, similar to pandas? tx